# How to test service layer, using @Autowired in springMVC and java7 level language. UnsupportedClassVersionError problem

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit

I try to implement a test for spring MVC (v3.12) project, using Mokito library. But I have the limitation in that what I need to use Java 1.7. and SpringMVC 3.x. So, when I try to use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` or `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` I get the error `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

In another case (when I delete string with `@RunWith` annotation), I get null definition `userService` object, when I determine it by `@Autowired`, or other annotation.

Better if I show part of the test (I use follow [tutorial](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/spring-boot-mockito-junit-example/)):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) //1
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml"})

public class QuadraticEquationServiceTest3 {

@InjectMocks
private UserService userService;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
public void loadTest(){

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(1);
    user.setName("java");

    when(userRepository.getUserById(1)).thenReturn(user);

    User testUser = userService.getUserById(1); //2
    //....
}

}
```

In this case, I get the error:
`java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

- Need to note: When I check 8 JDK version in IDE, I get the following exception:

  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load TestContextBootstrapper [null]. Specify @BootstrapWith's 'value' attribute or make the default bootstrapper class available.

When I delete `@RunWith...`, I get `NullPointerException` in string `2` (`userService` object).

When I create `userService` by `new UserService()`, I get the `nullPointerException` in `UserService` class, when project try to call `userRepository` object.

## Question:

Why I did not can to call service object, using `@Autowired`?
How to implement repository mock in testing service layer in Spring MVC + Java 1.7?

---

## additional info:

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Transactional
    public User getUserById(long id) {
        return userRepository.getUserbiId(id);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public class QuadraticEquationRepository implements QuadraticDAORepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public User getUserById(long id) {
        User u;
        Session session;
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        try {
            u = (User) session.load(User.class, id);
        } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e ){
            return null;
        }
        return u;
    }

}
```

pom.xml (part with Spring and test dependencies):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.exercise</groupId>
<artifactId>quadraticEquation</artifactId>

<name>quadraticEquation</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <spring-version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <hibernate-version>4.2.7.Final</hibernate-version>
    <mysql-version>5.1.27</mysql-version>
    <apache-connection-pooling-version>1.4</apache-connection-pooling-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="quadratic" />

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <!-- <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" /> -->
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
          p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>quadratic.model.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing different jars from a framework. You are mixing 3.2.9, 5.1.5 and 5.1.3. That is obviously trouble waiting to happen. NExtyour test doesn't make sense as you are mocking everything, then why load a context. Also if you follow a tutorial then follow the tutorial, you are making up your own dependencies. Finally you should be using `@RunWIth(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` instead of running this with the spring context framework.

Comment: And finally, don't use `@Autowired` on fields; wire dependencies through constructors, and you can eliminate Spring for most of your tests.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand. Do I need to refusal from @Autowired in my project?

Comment: @M.Deinum @M.Deinum thanks. You just extend my question. If I can not include spring-test dependency 5.1.5 version - I will not be using `SpringRunner` and `ContextConfiguration` annotation. But in my task, I must use springMVC 3.x version

Comment: I nowhere said you cannot include `spring-test` you shouldn't be mixing versions. Also for this test you don't need the `SpringRunner` or in the older versoin the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner `.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks. Resolwed!